# How can I get the name of all Test Cases in a Robotframework Test Suite

Tags: python, robotframework

In Robotframework I can get the current Test name or the current Test Suite with built in variables, such as:

```
log to console  TestName: ${TEST NAME}
log to console  SuiteName: ${SUITE NAME}
```

Now, anyone knows if I can get and print all Test Cases in the current Test Suite? Like a list of names, for example?

I can't find a variable with that information.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Pekka but I took a look in that link before and none. Can't find a variable with that information.

Answer (score 0):

set variable at ending or beginning of every test case and add them in list at ending of test suite

```
${cnt}=   Set Variable   ${0}
```

following 2 lines need to add at every test case

```
Set suite variable  ${TestCase1}     ${TEST NAME}
${cnt}=   Set Variable   ${cnt+1}
```

this lines are final at ending of testsuite

```
@{TestCases}=    Create List
:FOR   ${index}  IN RANGE  0   ${cnt}
\    Append To List     ${TestCases}   ${TestCase${Index}}
```

Then use this list `@{TestCases}`

Comment: Hi, this works only if I run the whole suite and all TCs in the same suite execution.
I need to get the names even If I run a single TC of a suite, isolated.
For example: I run only one TC X in the suite 1, but in this TC X, I need to get the name of TC Y and TC Z of suite 1 that isn't running or scheduled.

Comment: I dont think it will work like that, the variable will get Initialize when you run testcase so it will return only executed testcases, otherwise it would have return anything, what you are trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Each TC has a corresponding Jenkins Job to execute the TCs due technical and business requirements and due passing parameters issue.
The objective is to each TC triggering the next TC (in the same suite) without the need of pass the name statically.
So the workaround I found for this, was to set de chaining in Jenkins Jobs and not in the TC (inside RF). Só "job A will trigger job B directly" and not "TC A trigger Job B" like initially thought.